# Is there a way I can put my post templates in a separate folder?

Tags: templates

I have some custom post/page template files I would like to keep better organized by placing them into a  folder inside my themes directory. Is this possible, or would I need a line of code in my functions.php file?

If so, what is the line for functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add to the `single_template` filter. Check out [this article](http://www.unfocus.com/2010/08/10/including-page-templates-from-a-wordpress-plugin/) for more.